# How to perform actions periodically in Erlang

Tags: timer, erlang, periodic-task, periodic-processing

```
-define(INTERVAL, 1000).

init([]) ->
    Timer = erlang:send_after(?INTERVAL, self(), tick),
    {ok, Timer}.

handle_info(tick, OldTimer) ->
    erlang:cancel_timer(OldTimer),
    io:format("Tick ~w~n", [OldTimer]),
    Timer = erlang:send_after(?INTERVAL, self(), tick).
    {noreplay, Timer}.

start_clock() ->
    {_, Timer} = init([]),
    spawn(clock, handle_info, [tick, Timer]).
```

My codes is as above, but the output is not what I want.
How can I integrate init() and handle_info() into the main function(start_clock)?

Comment: What /is/ your output? What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: Is that all the code there is? In my answer I assumed those were callbacks in a gen_server.

Comment: Relevant: [What's the best way to do something periodically in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769466/whats-the-best-way-to-do-something-periodically-in-erlang?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
start_timer() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, clock}, ?MODULE, [], []).
```

Comment: in what sense does it answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

In the [timer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4) module, the function `apply_interval(Time, Module, Function, Arguments)` executes Module:Function(Arguments) every interval of Time. It takes care of spawning a process, returns a reference to allow a cancellation later.

You also can have a look at `send_interval(Time, Pid, Message)` in the same library.

You can also implement a simple loop like:

```
loop(Args,Tick) when is_integer(Tick), Tick >= 0 ->
    receive
        stop -> stopped
    after 
        Tick ->
            do_something(Args),
            {NewArgs,NewTick} = new_args(Args,Tick), 
            loop(NewArgs,NewTick)
    end.
```

it is not a realtime timer, but the function new_args(Args,Tick) can help to correct the deviation due to process scheduling.