# How to print out a value periodically in Erlang

Tags: timer, erlang

Im trying to simply get this Erlang program to print out a value periodically and I'm using this module to do so:

```
   -module(hot).
   -export([start/0,handle_info/2,  add/1]).

   start() ->
           Num = 0,
           timer:send_interval(1000, interval),
           {ok, Num}.

   handle_info(interval, Num) ->
          erlang:display(0),
          {noreply, Num}.

   add(X) ->
          X+2.
```

I'm referencing one of the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769466/whats-the-best-way-to-do-something-periodically-in-erlang)

I also tried using a modification from the top answer as follows:

```
init([]) ->
  Timer = erlang:send_after(1, self(), check),
  {ok, Timer}.

handle_info(check, OldTimer) ->
  erlang:cancel_timer(OldTimer),
  erlang:display(0),
  Timer = erlang:send_after(1000, self(), check),
  {noreply, Timer}.
```

Nothing prints out in either case.  It just tells me something like {ok,<0.43.0>}.  It seems that handle_info is never called at all.

Comment: of course. It would be better if you write what you are doing (which functions call) and what you expect to see on the display.

Comment: erlang:display(0).  Just display 0.  At this point it doesnt matter what it is, its just an experiment.  I just call init() or start().

Comment: You misunderstood me, I want to know what you want to get as a result. handle_info - is used for the handling of spontaneous messages in gen_server OTP. You have to process the message received from the timer.

Comment: I'm brand new to Erlang and I must just not understand whats going on here.  Ultimately all I want is for a value to be printed onto the screen every second.  Perhaps this is the entirely wrong approach?  The message itself isn't something I really care about, it will always be the same message--display a value to the screen.

Comment: I just badly know English, so I want to make sure that the correctly understood the problem before answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show the value of every second you can, for example, as follows:

```
-module(test).
-export([start/1]).

start(Num) when not is_number(Num)-> {error,not_a_number};
start(Num)->spawn(fun()->print(Num) end).

print(Num)->
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), []),
    receive
          {timeout, Tref, _} ->
            erlang:cancel_timer(Tref),
            io:format("~p~n",[Num]),
            if
                Num =:=0 -> io:format("Stop~n");
                true -> print(Num-1)
            end
    end.
```

For information about this function and its arguments, you can read the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send_after-3). Such a method is more [effecient](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html#id60818) than the use of the timer module.