# gen_server terminates with reason: bad return value

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I was following this example of executing periodic tasks given by Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378523/how-to-run-a-erlang-process-periodically-with-precise-time-i-e-10ms).

And i ran into a problem as I wanted to pass some Arguments also to the start_link function which would be used inside my do_task() function. But as given [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-4) the start_link/4 needs to return {ok,Pid} and in my case it is returning {ok,{Ref,Arguments}} and thus is failing.

How I can I fix this up.Here's my code:

```
start_link(Period,SERVER,Args) when Period > 0, is_integer(Period) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, SERVER}, ?MODULE, [Period,Args], []).


init([Period,Args]) ->
    StartT = erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond),
    self() ! tick,
    {ok, {StartT, Period,Args}}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.


handle_info(tick, {StartT, Period,Args} = S) ->
    Next = Period - (erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond)-StartT) rem Period,
    _Timer = erlang:send_after(Next, self(), tick),

    do_task(Args),
    {ok, S};

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.
```

Here 
Period is->30000
and Arguments is -> {A,[a,b],'something'}

And here is the crash log

```
[error] gen_server '95ef60ae-b2fa-491a-821d-ffae85cc57f6' terminated with reason: bad return value: {ok,{-576460723187,30000,{A,[a,b],'something'}}
```

Comment: `handle_info` (http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_info-2) cannot return an 'ok' tuple.

Comment: Sorry, missed such a simple instruction.Many thanks @pdexter.

Answer (score 3):

[`handle_info` cannot return an `ok` tuple.](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_info-2)

(Answer given as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984194/gen-server-terminates-with-reason-bad-return-value#comment90920741_51984194).)

Comment: More generally, handle_info should return a noreply tuple. I got a similar error (in Elixir) because of a code path that only returned "state".