# Dynamically load config file in Emqttd

Tags: erlang, mqtt

Load Config File Dynamically in Emqttd.

Can I make changes to emq.conf file and anyhow load it without stopping the broker ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to use "gen_server" with ETS table to store/update data periodically (for example every 30 seconds).

you may use `erlang:send_after` inside the `handle_info` function & read Emqttd config file.

check the answer in this topic [What's the best way to do something periodically in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769466/whats-the-best-way-to-do-something-periodically-in-erlang)